# How to force Mac to shutdown when the lid is closed (for compliance requirement)

Tags: macos

I'm looking for a terminal command to force the Mac to shut down when the lid is closed to meet our compliance requirement.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you mean that you wish the Mac to shutdown rather than go to sleep? Or do you mean that it doesn't go to sleep when the lid is closed?

Comment: What precisely is the "compliance requirement"? There is almost no difference, security-wise, between the two. The only difference is battery consumption.

Comment: @Tetsujin Macs can do all sorts of things while sleeping, e.g. backups, being woken up by Bluetooth or keyboard events, etc. So it's not the same as being shut down (where the only way to power it on is to press the power button).

Comment: Se https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/can-i-change-the-action-that-occurs-when-i-close-my-laptops-lid . You can enforce *hibernation* on lid close, which does perform a *full* shutdown, though preserving machine state.

Comment: @slhck - I don't see how any of those would go against a compliance requirement. My partner works for an international bank & their compliance is heinous… but it doesn't include shutting a computer down, only securing it against penetration.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration.
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/463943/how-to-force-mac-to-shutdown-when-the-lid-is-closed-not-interested-in-sleep-or

Comment: Ask the people who wrote your compliance rules if they know whether this is possible.

Comment: @benwiggy - they obviously have no clue at all. The requirement is out of date by at least a decade.

Comment: Not sure what‘s easier: to convince Apple to implement a shutdown-on-close option, or to change a compliance rule.

Comment: @nohillside - unstoppable force meets immovable object ;) Considering the number of companies who still, a decade after just about every government & security authority in the world said changing passwords frequently is less secure… both seem equally unlikely.